# Diluting oil based undercoat

Tags: painting, board

I have erected false walls using osb boards on the face of plastered brick wall to accommodate some photo frames and decorative items. Total surface area is 8'×8'.

My intention is to paint the osb board using high gloss white paint. This paint requires primer to be painted first.

Since osb naturally have tiny holes and voids, i think the primer must be diluted for easy flowing into those voids and gaps.

To keep the cost low, can i use petrol (gasoline) for thinning the primer?  The paint thinner cost 6 times higher than the petrol in Malaysia.

Pls advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use mineral spirits or mythle-hydride to dilute oil based paints. I don't really think that diluting the primer is the best solution though. It would be best to lay it on thick with a heavily padded roller and then back roll it out. Primers job is to seal and adhere. Thinning it will only prevent it from doing its job.

Comment: Thank you. In that case i just use the primer as it is and then dilute the gloss paint with thinner instead. In that way the paint will flow into the gaps and voids.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Joe, I suggest using a thicker paint roller. Look for a roller that works well for stucco ceilings. Deffenitly dont use gasoline, that will make your house smell horrible and not good for your health to breath in. Once you have applied the primer use a thinner roller for the high gloss coat to leave a nice smooth finish.